# My category select input is adding an extra nil category to my posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `many-to-many` association between my Post and Category model.
I added the category field as a nested attribute of post:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
```

**posts/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]} %>
```

**categorization.rb:**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :post_id, :position

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**category.rb:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations  

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 14 }
end
```

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :category_ids

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations  
end

<%= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]} %>
```

Now, after submitting the form i get something like this:

```
[#<Category id: 2, name: "Design", created_at: "2012-11-23 10:12:54", updated_at: "2012-11-23 10:12:54">, #<Category id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

I have no idea where the extra nil category is comming from.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

**post new:**

[image]

**generated html after submission:**

[image]

Comment: First of all, you should not call `Category` model directly from the view. Do it in your controller, and save it in instance variable. Not that it solves your problem, but it's worth noting :)

Comment: Did you know about `collection_select`? This is perfect for such cases: `t.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name`

Comment: @ckruse Thanks, it works, but still getting that strange nil category.

Comment: @alexchenco Could you paste the generated HTML?

Comment: @alexchenco sorry, I was talking about the HTML of the form you are submitting :-)

Comment: @ckruse Ha, it crossed my mind. Please see my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a problem in the HTML or Rails code. I think you have an data integrity problem.

If I were you I would check if there is a `Categorization` entry in the database pointing to a no longer existing category.

Also, maybe you want to check out the `:dependent` attribute for relations in rails to achieve data integrity, e.g. I would have written `has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy` or `has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :delete` in both models, `Post` and `Category`. This has the effect that if you delete a post or category via rails all references are destroyed, too.

Comment: I did `Category.destroy_all` and `Categorization.destroy_all`. Then `Category.create(name: "Programming")`, selected it on the post form and submitted. Still getting that `nil` category.

Comment: some output form the console: `[#<Category id: 3, name: "Programming", created_at: "2012-11-23 11:46:16", updated_at: "2012-11-23 11:46:16">, #<Category id: 4, name: "Design", created_at: "2012-11-23 11:46:23", updated_at: "2012-11-23 11:46:23">]` and `[#<Categorization id: 11, post_id: 308, category_id: 3, position: nil, created_at: "2012-11-23 11:47:48", updated_at: "2012-11-23 11:47:48">] `

Comment: By the way, I couldn't put `Category.all` in an instance variable (@category) in the post show action in the controller. It becomes `nil`. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem. Had this in my post controller:

```
 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @replies = @post.replies.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @reply = @post.replies.build
    @category = @post.categories.build # this was the problem
    @vote = Vote.new
    store_location
  end
```

Comment: if the .build is the problem, what did you do resolve it? I have similar problem